# QPainter in pyqt5 is not painting anything when calling repaint() in a loop. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pyqt, pyqt5

I am totally new to PyQt. I want to do animation using PyQt5 .This is a simple test I am doing , so I am just trying to move a rectangle from top to the bottom of the window. Here's a gist of what I am doing to achieve this.

  1. I have put whatever I wanted to paint inside paintEvent() method. I have painted the rectangle using variables not constant values

  2. I have also created a update() function to update all the variables

  3. I have created a loop function which calls self.update() and self.repaint() every 100 milliseconds

```py
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QMainWindow)             
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDateTime

class rain_animation(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.painter = QPainter()

        """ Variables for the Window """
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500

        """Variables for the rain"""
        self.rain_x = self.width/2
        self.rain_y = 0
        self.rain_width = 5
        self.rain_height = 30
        self.rain_vel_x = 0
        self.rain_vel_y = 5

        self.start()
        self.loop()

    def paintEvent(self, a0):

        self.painter.begin(self)

        # Draw a White Background
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white, Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        #Draw the rain
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue, 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.blue, Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.painter.drawRect(self.rain_x, self.rain_y, self.rain_width, self.rain_height)

        self.painter.end(self)

    def update(self, diff):
        self.rain_x += self.rain_vel_x
        self.rain_y += self.rain_vel_y

    def start(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Rain Animation")
        self.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def loop(self):
        start = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        while True :    
            diff = start.msecsTo(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
            if diff >= 100 :
                print("time : {0} ms rain_x : {1} rain_y : {2}".format(diff, self.rain_x, self.rain_y))
                start = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
                self.update(diff)
                self.repaint()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    animation = rain_animation()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I should see is a rectangle moving from the top of window to the bottom of the screen but all I see is a window with a black background.
The loop() function seems working properly since the data I am printing shows that the variables are being updated every 100 milliseconds.
 
Though the problem seems to be something in the loop() function since after removing the self.loop() I can see a static picture of the blue box with a white background at the top of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem:

Having a continuous loop does not allow the GUI to perform tasks such as painting, interaction with the OS, etc. Each GUI provides a way to make animations in a way that does not block the window.

---

Qt provides various classes that allow you to implement the animation as:

- QTimer,
- QTimeLine,
- QVariantAnimation,
- QPropertyAnimation.

On the other hand it is recommended that:

- Do not create a QPainter outside of paintEvent if it is going to be responsible for the GUI painting.
- Use the update() method (not your method but the one that provides Qt) instead of repaint, in case repaint will force the window to paint sometimes unnecessarily, instead update() will do it when necessary, remember that the painted is done with the refresh rate of the screen (60 Hz). For example, if you call repaint 5 times in 20 ms then paintEvent() will be called 3 times but the painting on the screen is every 16.6ms so you only need 1 paint, in the case of update() if you consider it.

---

Considering the above, it is best to use a QPropertyAnimation:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RainAnimation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rain Animation")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)
        self.m_rect_rain = QtCore.QRect()

        animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self,
            b"rect_rain",
            parent=self,
            startValue=QtCore.QRect(self.width() / 2, 0, 5, 30),
            endValue=QtCore.QRect(self.width() / 2, self.height() - 30, 5, 30),
            duration=5 * 1000,
        )

        animation.start()

    def paintEvent(self, a0):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # Draw a White Background
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        #Draw the rain
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect_rain)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QRect)
    def rect_rain(self):
        return self.m_rect_rain

    @rect_rain.setter
    def rect_rain(self, r):
        self.m_rect_rain = r
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RainAnimation()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another option is use QVarianAnimation:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RainAnimation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rain Animation")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)
        self.m_rect_rain = QtCore.QRect()

        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            parent=self,
            startValue=QtCore.QRect(self.width() / 2, 0, 5, 30),
            endValue=QtCore.QRect(self.width() / 2, self.height() - 30, 5, 30),
            duration=5 * 1000,
            valueChanged=self.set_rect_rain,
        )
        animation.start()

    def paintEvent(self, a0):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # Draw a White Background
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        # Draw the rain
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.m_rect_rain)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    def set_rect_rain(self, r):
        self.m_rect_rain = r
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RainAnimation()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The following example is using your logic but with a QTimer:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class RainAnimation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rain Animation")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)
        self.m_rect_rain = QtCore.QRect(self.width() / 2, 0, 5, 30)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.update_rain, interval=100)
        timer.start()

    def paintEvent(self, a0):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # Draw a White Background
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        # Draw the rain
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(self.m_rect_rain)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_rain(self):
        self.m_rect_rain.moveTop(self.m_rect_rain.top() + 5)
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RainAnimation()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks worked Perfectly !!! I used the QTimer approach since it seems much more flexible than the other approaches

Comment: @SaritDas In my case I prefer QPropertyAnimation since the movement is smoother and optimized

Comment: I was wondering what would happen if the calculations in the update_rain() take more than 100 milliseconds

Comment: I want to use these pyqt features to build games , 3D Graphics Engines with collision detection, lighting and shadow features completely from scratch. I those cases calculations can sometimes take a lot of time . That is why i was wondering what happens if calculations in update_rain() functions take more time than specified in the interval = time part

Comment: @SaritDas You will see how an element jumps from one position to another, the movement will be abrupt. TL; DR: I recommend not creating it from scratch since you probably do not get anything good, Qt already offers a module for 3d: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html, that module already optimized certain tasks using the GPU. As you put it, it seems that you plan to implement everything with CPU so you will have many undesirable problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to build 3D Graphics Engines not because I would use them in some projects or games (though I may), but purely for educational purposes . Say I want to build it and using python should I look for something else like pyOpenGl or is there a way do it in pyQt ??

Comment: @SaritDas It can be done with PyQt or pyOpenGl (PyQt also supports OpenGL) but another thing is that you get good results, that will depend on you. Bye.